# $ZSH_VERSION not being printed

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I have a test.zsh script that contains `echo $ZSH_VERSION` and it outputs nothing.  From the command line,  `echo $ZSH_VERSION` prints `5.8`.  Is there a reason why this variable is null inside a zsh script? I am runing macOS 11.1.

Comment: Put `#!/bin/zsh` as the very first line in your shell script.  The default interpreter for shell scripts on macOS is `/bin/sh`. `zsh` is the default for *interactive* shells, i.e. those launched from Terminal.  A bit more here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50667/432774 and here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-bang

Comment: @Brando : This means that your script is not executed by zsh. Execute it with the command `zsh test.zsh` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, file name extensions like `.zsh` mean nothing to Unix shells. What matters when sourcing a script is the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) on the first line of the script. If you want your script to be interpreted by `zsh` instead, then you need to put this as the first line of your script:

```
#!/bin/zsh
```